# How to add same `option` element to two different `select` lists?

Tags: javascript

I have a small JS sample of trying to add the same `option` element to two different `select` lists, but it seems whenever I try to do this the `option` only gets added to the second of the two lists, and I'm not sure why.

HTML:

```
<select id='one'></select>
<select id='two'></select>
<input type='button' value='click' onclick='ftn();' />
```

Javascript:

```
function ftn() {
    var one = document.getElementById("one");
    var two = document.getElementById("two");

    var option = document.createElement("option");

    option.value = "cool";
    option.innerText = "beans";

    one.appendChild(option);
    two.appendChild(option);
};
```

Result:

[image: Result]

I can achieve the desired result of having the content of this one `option` element be present in both `select` lists, but that requires I create two different `option` elements, and just make their data the same.

Is there a way I can accomplish this, in Javascript, using only one option element?

Also, here's a link to the CodePen I wrote for this: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SirToadstool/pen/XWKwqqa)

Comment: create the element twice. an element can only belong in one place.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that using only one option element.

Comment: No, HTML elements can only have one parent.  You need to add two identical `option` elements.

Comment: So this is then appending the option to the first list, then taking that same element from the first list and "moving" it to the second?

Comment: @Delfino Yes.  Read the doc on `appendChild`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.  An element can only have one parent, so to add the same `option` element to two different `select` list, you must duplicate the `option`.

The [MDN documentation on `appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) says this:

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).
> This means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So **if the node already has a parent, the node is first removed, then appended at the new position**. The Node.cloneNode() method can be used to make a copy of the node before appending it under the new parent. Note that the copies made with cloneNode will not be automatically kept in sync.

So your code is appending the `option` to the first `select`, then moving it to the second.  You can clone the `option` to get it into both `select` elements.